# Plaintext word list with filters for word class

Tags: web-apps, dictionary

I'm looking for a long plaintext word list like Enable2k or YAWL for Windows, but filtered by word classes (really I only need nouns, adjectives and verbs. Anything else is superfluous.) Is there an online tool that can generate a plaintext list based on requirements like word class? I'd prefer not to have to use an API (entirely new to them,) but if that's the only option then I'll learn.